# Add summary row in vaadin table

Tags: vaadin

I want to add a summary row on end of my table. Is there a standard function of com.vaadin.ui.Table that I can use?

Comment: It is also worth noting that if you are new to the Vaadin you may probably want to use Grid instead of the Table. But whatever suits you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vaadin Table known of headers and footers.
[Here is the Documentation for it](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html).

```
// Set the footers
table.setFooterVisible(true);
table.setColumnFooter("Name", "Average");
table.setColumnFooter("Died At Age", String.valueOf(avgAge));
```

Generating the content of the footer is your responsibility, so you have to do the sums/average or other calculations.